# Improve this nested loop to work better in Mastermind

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> co = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> gu = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println(code.size());
System.out.println(guess1.size());
for(int b = 0; b < code.size(); b++) {     
 for (int i = 0; i < guess1.size(); i++){
    if(guess1.get(i).equals(code.get(b)) && (i == b) && ((Arrays.asList(co).contains((b))))&&(!(Arrays.asList(gu).contains(i)))){
        co.add(b);
        gu.add(i);
        hintboard.add(Hints.B);`enter code here`
        System.out.println(guess1);
        System.out.println(co);
        System.out.println(gu);
    }else if(guess1.get(i).equals(code.get(b)) && (!(Arrays.asList(co).contains((b))))&&(!(Arrays.asList(gu).contains(i)))){
        co.add(b);
        gu.add(i);
        hintboard.add(Hints.W);
        //System.out.println(hintboard);
```

What I am trying to do here is that, check if `i` is equal to `b` at the same position and make sure the index is not present in arrayList of `co` and `gu`. however the statement is true every time even though the first index of `b` is added in `co` and the index of `i` is added to `gu`.

Comment: Aside from the unnecessary brackets, what do you think you're doing with `Arrays.asList(co).contains((b))`? Because that will always return `false` (because `co` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`, so `Arrays.asList(co)` is a `List<ArrayList<Integer>>`, which should never contain `i`, an `Integer`).

Comment: So what exactly is your question here?  Is something not working?  If something is broken, we need to know what it is.  If the code works, then it is off-topic for Stack Overflow (though may be suitable for our friends at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if i understood your whole problem, but here it goes anyways:
Your problem is that you use:

```
Arrays.asList(co).contains((b))
```

First of all the parentheses around b is unnecessary/useless so you should remove them.
And the reason it doesnt work is that Arrays.asList will create a list with all the elements passed into it. The intended use would be something like this:

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

Which will return the list:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Your code puts a list in to a list so the output would be something like this:

```
[[YOUR, LIST, ITEMS]]
```

and your code of `Arrays.asList(co).contains((b))` will do a test similar to this psudo-code:

```
[[1, 2, 3]].contains(2)
```

This will always return false since the main list does not contain `2` it only contains a sublist `[1, 2, 3]` It would work if you did this `Arrays.asList(co).get(0).contains((b))` as `.get(0)` would return the first sublist, but this only correct a mistake you created, so the correct way to write the line in the first place would be:

```
co.contains(b)
```

I can not tell you if your code works as a whole, after this fix, as there is many ways to play mastermind, and i am not sure of the rules you play by. Also I do not fully understand the full process of your code, only the concept. Anyways here is your corrected code (Hope this helped you understand):

```
ArrayList<Integer> co = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> gu = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println(code.size());
System.out.println(guess1.size());
for(int b = 0; b < code.size(); b++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < guess1.size(); i++) {
        if (guess1.get(i).equals(code.get(b)) && (i == b) && co.contains(b) && !gu.contains(i)) {
            co.add(b);
            gu.add(i);
            hintboard.add(Hints.B);
            System.out.println(guess1);
            System.out.println(co);
            System.out.println(gu);
        } else if (guess1.get(i).equals(code.get(b)) && !co.contains(b) && !gu.contains(i)) {
            co.add(b);
            gu.add(i);
            hintboard.add(Hints.W);
            //System.out.println(hintboard);
        }
    }
}
```